# Insert into mysql if postid is new, else update

Tags: mysql

I am facing this situation. I want to insert into a database like this :

```
INSERT INTO 
`mytable` (`id`, `post_id`, `user_id`, `dtime`) 
VALUES ('','$pid','$uid',NOW())"
```

The ID column is primary and with auto-increment. And I need to check if the post_id is not getting inserted twice.

Any idea on how to do that, so that if the post_id exists, it does an update, without needing two queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

This link was the second result when I searched for "mysql insert or update" on Google.

Comment: Thanks René, however the following returns an empty result set (post_id is unique) :

`INSERT INTO `corrections` (`post_id`, `user_id`,`status`, `encours`) VALUES ('25','1','En cours',NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `encours` = 'En cours'`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `REPLACE` query. It does exactly what you need, and looks like an INSERT except it starts with "REPLACE INTO"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html